# Defining conditional routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been searching for something similar but no luck. I want to build an app that uses different controllers for same urls. Basic idea is like that if a user is logged in as admin he uses lets say admin controller, if user is just a user he uses user controller. This is just an example, basically I want to have a function that decides what controller route takes.

Thank u everyone. Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS
Use of this:
Admin has different UI and options,
Output catching,
Separation of concern

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a RouteConstraint to check the user's role, as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Examples.Extensions
{
    public class MustBeAdmin : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public MustBeAdmin()
        { }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) 
        {
            // return true if user is in Admin role
            return httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, before your default route, declare a route for the Admin role, as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Admins", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter default
    new { controller = new MustBeAdmin() }  // our constraint
);
```

counsellorben

Comment: this tipp helped me, too!

Comment: where it is mention in code if user login as normal user then he/she will be redirected to user controller?