# ASP.net MVC conditional default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, conditional-statements, default

Is it possible to create a conditional default route?

I would like the change the default route based on the logged on the current user's permission.

I'm currently creating the default route like so

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ActivityDashboard", action = "Activities", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: not possible directly, however you can do this using RouteConstraint. Validate user in your route constraint and act accordingly.

Comment: take a look at this, you could get some idea here... [Conditional Routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888079/defining-conditional-routes)

Comment: I've seen that, but would that be applicable for the default route?