# ASP.Net MVC : How conditional routing works

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am not advance developer in MVC.

i just read a post from this url [Defining conditional routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888079/defining-conditional-routes)

the question was if user login as admin then he will be redirect to admin controller and if user login as normal user then he will be redirected as user controller.

this was things has been done but i just do not understand the code how it is working. so help me to understand the code.

```
using System;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Examples.Extensions
{
    public class MustBeAdmin : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public MustBeAdmin()
        { }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) 
        {
            // return true if user is in Admin role
            return httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
        }
    }
}

routes.MapRoute(
    "Admins", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter default
    new { controller = new MustBeAdmin() }  // our constraint
);
```

1) **bool Match()** is any in built method or is it user define one ?

2) already action and controller mention this way in route

```
new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

but again mention the same like this way

```
new { controller = new MustBeAdmin() }
```

3) what is the meaning of this line `{ controller = new MustBeAdmin() } ?`

nowhere it is specific that if user login as normal user then he will be redirected to user controller.

please help me to understand the code.

thanks

Comment: why negative marking. i want to understand how route constrain works and that is why i post it.

Comment: Intellisense and the internet should answer theses questions for you http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your logic flipped. Here’s how you can use the NotEqual constraint to exclude the /Admin pages from the Default route:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
{
  private string _match = String.Empty;

  public NotEqual(string match)
  {
    _match = match;
  }

  public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
  {
    return !httpContext.User.IsInRole(_match);
  }
}

routes.MapRoute(
  "Admins", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter default
  new { controller = new NotEqual("Admin") }
);
```

It's never going to match for a non-admin.

`Match` is a method on the [`IRouteConstraint` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint(v=vs.110).aspx):

Comment: Not necessarily. I think if no route is found you'll get a 404 but you can handle that with a global default route or a custom 404 page.

Comment: can u redirect me to right article which guide me how to handle 404 error if no route found? i like to know also how to handle that with a global default route or a custom 404 page. looking for your further help. thanks